# Too many redirects with login session example

Tags: php, html

I followed [this guide](https://www.formget.com/login-form-in-php/) because I'm trying to figure out how to get a log-in session to work, yet once I log in, I keep getting an error from my browser that my server

> redirected you too many times.

I believe the issue is with **session.php** because if I take out session.php and any dependents in my other code, it works *just fine*.

```
<?php
//Establishing Connection with Server by passing
//server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

//Selecting Database
$db = mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_NAME);
session_start(); //starting session

//storing session
$user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];

//SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information of User
$ses_sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT StoreID FROM Store WHERE StoreID='$user_check'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);

$login_session = $row['StoreID'];

if(!isset($login_session)){
    mysqli_close($connection); //Closing connections
    header('Location: fakeindex.php'); //Redirecting to Home Page
}
?>
```

There are are a lot of other users complaining about the same problem but the author just writes them off and/or ignores them. What's the issue?

**fakeindex.php**

```
<?php
include('login.php'); // Includes Login Script

if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
    header("location: profile.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Form in PHP with Session</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <h1>PHP Login Session Example</h1>
    <div id="login">
        <h2>Login Form</h2>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <label>UserName :</label>
            <input id="name" name="username" placeholder="username" type="text">
            <label>Password :</label>
            <input id="password" name="password" placeholder="**********" type="password">
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value=" Login ">
            <span><?php echo $error; ?></span>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start(); // Starting Session
$error=''; // Variable to Store Error Message

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
    }
    else {
        require_once("db_const.php");
        // Define $username and $password
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];

        //Establishing connection with server by passing
        //server_name, user_id and password as a parameter

        $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Connection to the database failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_errno());
        }

        //To Protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
        $username = stripslashes($username);
        $password = stripslashes($password);
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $username);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $password);

        //Selecting Database
        $db = mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_NAME);

        //SQL query to fetch information of registered users and finds user match.
        $query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM Store WHERE StoreID='$username' AND StorePassword='$password'");
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

        if ($rows == 1) {
            $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username; //Initializing session
            header("location: profile.php"); //Redirecting to other page
        }
        else {
            $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
        }
        mysqli_close($connection); //Closing connection
    }
}
?>
```

**profile.php**

```
<?php
include('session.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Your Home Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="profile">
        <b id="welcome">Welcome : <i><?php echo $login_session; ?></i></b>
        <b id="logout"><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></b>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(session_destroy()) {//Destroying all sessions
    header("Location: fakeindex.php"); //Redirecting to home page
}
```

Comment: do you have any headers in other files? and/or a mod rewrite? or includes, could be anything really. You should add an `exit;` for headers too.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah, I do. I was going to share them but I essentially copy-and-pasted the code in the hyperlinked tutorial. The only things I changed were updating some dated `mysql` to `mysqli` functions.

Comment: well there you go, and it might be a "logic" thing here. I edited my comment above to add `exit;` after each header otherwise your code might want to continue to execute. Maybe there's a conditional statement that's off somewhere. Hard to say without seeing everything and how it all works together.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I added `exit;` after each header in my files but I still get the same redirect error.

Comment: you'll need to post your full code and as to how it all works together. Plus, if you've anything in `.htaccess` that may be rewriting, that could also be it. I have to leave for a while. If you do post your full code, I'll have a look at it when I get back, or if someone is here, they'll probably be able to figure it out.

Comment: `SELECT StoreID`, then two lines later I see `$row['username'];` Where did you select the username? Infact, if you `echo "'$login_session'";` what does it output? I think it must be `$row['StoreID'];`

Comment: I posted the rest of the code

Comment: If your goal is to use the session why are you always reading the db? Should check session first to determine if reading the db is necessary.

Comment: @developerwjk From my introductory sentence, "I followed this guide because I'm trying to figure out how to get a log-in session to work". In other words, I don't know how log-in sessions work or how to do them so I was trying to learn though that tutorial. Other people commented on said tutorial with the same issue.  `$_SESSION['login_user']` is defined in `login.php`.

Comment: @Xorifelse I think you're onto something there. All it's outputting is `''`. I keep changing the query and cant get anything useful out of it.

Comment: @8protons dont change the query, change `$login_session = $row['username'];` to `$login_session = $row['StoreID'];`

Comment: @Xorifelse Still getting the redirect error. I tried echoing `$login_session` and just get `''`, which I don't get how because if the DB wasn't working or the query bad, I wouldnt be able to get pass my initial `fakeindex.php` script which will submit on successful credentials or respond with ""Username or Password is invalid"" if they're bad. Note that said script depends on login.php, so they're both working correctly from what I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session sometimes depending on your system and your code, will not work unless you have a `session_id("sessionID")`, I used to have this problem too. it's a method and a way I used.

You also have a database clarified, when you already have one. With `mysqli_connect()` you just put the database name at the end, which you have already done.

## So what do you do about the sessions?

---

Well, I have my own solution that I have used.

```
<?php

// edit the `mysqli_connect` to your requirements.
$connect = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "password", "database");

// since you have the database already defined then you don't need to:
// mysqli_select_db();
 
// let's start the session, and get things going.

session_id("mainID"); // you can rename this if you want.
session_start();

// set the session `login` too: `false`, if the session hasn't been set yet.
if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
  $_SESSION['login'] = false;
}

// and this is pretty much your solution.
?>
```

And you may want to move to MySQLi OOP, (AKA) Object Oriented Programming. It's more reliable, but since your are using just regular MySQLi.

And as a little extra to help you out, I'll point out a couple things for you to check out.

## Things to check for

---

1. you'll want to check your .htaccess to make sure you aren't messing anything up.
2. debug your code, like looking for closing brackets that are supposed to be there.

And here is some help on a login query:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['form'])) {

  // username and password

  // also if you want to make your password more secure, you can do a `sha1()`.
  $user = mysqli_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['username']));
  $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['password']));
  
  $query = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username='{$user}' AND
  password='".sha1($pass)."' LIMIT 1";

  // since you are not using OOP, I'll just do it this way.
  $set = mysqli_query($query);

  // basicly means:
  // if the user's input username and password equal to a row,
  // it will execute the code below.
  if(mysqli_num_rows($set) === 1) {

    // for safety reasons, NEVER, and
    // I mean EVER, store passwords in sessions or cookies.
    // People can get access to session and cookies,
    // so do not rely on cookies or sessions for storing passwords.

    $_SESSION['login'] = true;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
  }
}
?>
```

**NOTE:** OOP is very good for securing, like `bind_param()`, is great for user inputs, because it will tell the SQL statement what to expect. like `string` or `integer`.

Hope this helped!

Comment: I finally got it all working and adapted it to support your suggestions, such as the move to OOP. Since my first languages were object-oriented, this wasn't difficult. Thank you so incredibly much for your extremely useful answer. I only wish my post was better so that your answer would get the attention that it deserves. Take care.

Comment: Oh your welcome. Sorry I didn't get to this until now. :P So, yeah. I've only been developing with PHP for like 4 months now. And it appears I have learned a lot. But TRUST me, heehee. There is SOOOO much more to learn.