# Unable to redirect after login in using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, redirect

I want my user to redirected to page where user clicked `login` so i added following code to `config` file so that each and ever file has access to `redirect code`

**config.php**

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && basename($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) != basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) {
    $_SESSION['redirect_url'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}
```

So that when ever i need a redirect i can simple call like bellow

```
header('location:' . $_SESSION['redirect_url']);
exit();
```

and when i try above code i get error showing

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

i even tried `echo $_SESSION['redirect_url']` and it showed a valid `requested URL`

But it doesn't redirected. Can some one help me what wrong im doing.

and here is

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On

# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: And what is in your `.htaccess` file

Comment: @RiggsFolly updated with `.htaccess` in question.

Comment: have you tried adding exit(); below the header() - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553698/php-should-i-call-exit-after-calling-location-header

Comment: @PHPology yes `exit();` is present already still i get the redirect `error`

Comment: You're most likely trying to redirect to the same file which would be the reason it's throwing that error.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner yes i thought that, so i  tried to echo `$_SESSION['redirect_url']` and i get URL of last visited page like `/product.php?id=1234` here is the working example http://safebrowser.tk/

Comment: Ok. Well, if this is an .htaccess related question, I won't be of much help. If you try it without relying on .htaccess and it works, then you'll need to further debug/research this as to why it's acting that way.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner no this is not `.htaccess` related question i have added it because @RiggsFolly requested it. Can you please help me solving this.

Comment: Ok. While Googling, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37333326/1415724). That and other hits on Google. The search was `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS php sessions htaccess`.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner but i use `PDO` already

Comment: What I posted has nothing to do with PDO, just this part of their answer: *Session sometimes depending on your system and your code, will not work unless you have a session_id("sessionID"), I used to have this problem too. it's a method and a way I used.*

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner i did `session_start();
session_id();` in my `config.php` still i get `redirect` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after long research.

```
echo "<a href='/login.php?ref=". urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ."'>login</a>";
```

and in login.php

```
if ($_GET['ref'] != '') {
    $url = $_GET['ref'];
} else {
    $url = "/";
}

if ($user->login($username, $password)) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header("location:http://" .$url);
        exit();
    }
```

am using this simple method to redirect to requested page.